# how to build compiled rpm of gcc 8.2

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to make an rpm of gcc 8.2 for centos 7.

Honestly I am trying my best to understand how to use `rpmbuild` and `.spec` file, but it's too hard for me to understand.

I tried packaging my hello world program using [fedoraproject's tutorial](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_GNU_Hello_RPM_package) and succeded.

But when I tried building wget rpm using [ibm's Packaging software with RPM tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rpm1/index.html), I failed.

I am trying to build gcc 8.2(https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-8.2.0/gcc-8.2.0.tar.gz)

I use this process to build gcc, and I want the packaged rpm to do exactly like this, precompiled.

```
./configure --with-system-zlib --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++ --prefix=/opt/gcc-8.2.0

make -j 12

make install
```

Can anyone write an example spec file for me?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you use the src.rpm for it and the spec in it?

Unpack everything in the src.rpm but the spec file itself to ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/

Now unpack the spec file to your desired location (e.g Desktop) and edit it in the desired file editor (GUI based or text based doesn't matter).

I prefer nano or pluma.